# Predis Null bulk reply

Tags: php, redis, watch, reply, predis

Hy guys! I'm doing an optimistic locking in Predis. The problem is that the Redis documentation says that when the watched key is modified, then the execute returns a 'Null Multi-bulk reply'. How does it looks like in Predis? Sady I not found any useful docs for Pedis (not counting the very basic tutorials).

Here is how my code looks like at the moment:

```
private function updateUrlMaxProcessingTime($time, $hoursSinceUnixEpoch) {
    //Save the key and the field. They can change anytime because of the timestamp.
    $key = $this->statisticsConfig->getKeyFromDataName(StatisticsEnum::URL_MAX_PROCESS_TIME, $hoursSinceUnixEpoch);
    $field = $this->statisticsConfig->getFieldFromDataName(StatisticsEnum::URL_MAX_PROCESS_TIME, $hoursSinceUnixEpoch);

    //Update the max url processing time if necessary.
    $this->redis->watch($key);

    $val = $this->redis->hget($key, $field);
    if ($val < $time) {
        $this->redis->multi();
        $this->redis->hset($key, $field, $time);
        $result = $this->redis->exec();

        //TODO: fix this
        if ($result != null && $result[0] != null && $result[0] != -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $this->redis->unwatch();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I call the function as long as it's return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A null multi-bulk reply returned by Redis is simply translated as `NULL` by Predis, so when the client returns that from `EXEC` instead of an array it means that the transaction has been aborted by the server. In your script you should just check if `$result === null` (note the strict comparison) to safely catch aborted transactions.

Alternatively, instead of directly using `MULTI`, `EXEC` et al with Predis you can use a more high-level abstraction for transactions exposed by the `Predis\Client::multiExec()` method, in a similar way to how it is used in [this example](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v0.8.3/examples/MultiExecTransactionsWithCAS.php) with check-and-set and an optional automatic retry count for aborted transactions after which the client throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm using multiExec() from now on.